# Bound for $\Vert g\Vert_r$ when $ \Vert g-f\Vert_2<\varepsilon$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\varepsilon>0$ and $r\in[1,2)$. Define
$$ L_{r,\epsilon}:=\inf{\{\Vert g\Vert_r}:g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),\, \Vert g-f\Vert_2<\varepsilon\}$$
Can we find some upper bound for $L_{r,\epsilon}$?

Comment: Obviously not independently of $f$. Otherwise trivially yes: cut off a small tail of $f$ and apply Holder on the remaining set of finite measure.